# How can I replace "English" with "EN"?

Tags: i18n-l10n

I have 3 languages in my Drupal 8 site. All works fine, without the language switcher. 
Replacing *German* with *DE* worked, but replacing *English* with *EN* didn't work.

How can I replace *English* with *EN* in Drupal 8?

[image: All works fine, without the word English]

[image: All Languages where translated]

Comment: Simply disable the `locale` module BEFORE adding another language. https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/255940/15055

Answer (score 4):

I use this, it's a little bit more dynamic then if you would hardcode the language code yourself. Hope it helps. This example works with the language switcher block.

```
function theme_preprocess_links__language_block(&$variables) {
    foreach(array_keys($variables['links']) as &$code){
        $variables['links'][$code]['link']['#title'] = $code;
    }
}
```

Comment: Definitely this is most universal solution

Answer (score 2):

This is a Drupal 8 bug. I have had the same issue.

Add the following function to MYTHEME.theme file. (It should be located in the theme directory.) Replace MYTHEME with the machine name of your theme.

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_links__language_block(&$variables) {
  $variables['links']['en']['link']['#title'] = 'EN';
}
```

Comment: It's not a bug, it's a feature. https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/255940/15055

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using the language switcher block, you could change this in your template MYTHEME.theme file using an preprocess function.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_block().
 */
function MYTHEME_preprocess_block(&$variables) {
     if ($variables['elements']['#id'] == 'taalkeuze') { //My sites default language is Dutch hence the id 'taalkeuze' in Dutch.
         $variables['content']['#links']['en']['title'] = 'EN';
     }
}
```

I also tried an implementation of [hook_language_switch_links_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Language%21language.api.php/function/hook_language_switch_links_alter/8), but this did not work. I'm not sure why it didn't.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. And as temporary solution I've used this js:

```
(function ($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#block-languageswitcher li.fr a").text("FR");
    $("#block-languageswitcher li.de a").text("DE");
  }); 
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not a bug, it's a feature.

All you have to do is to have the `locale` module disabled before adding another language. So now *translations don't get imported automatically*. Afterwards simply enable locale again. And rename the language as you did.

That's it.

Answer (score 0):

The below snippet changes text of the language switcher block to a desired shortcode.

```
/**
 * Change the link title of the language block.
 */
function theme_preprocess_links(&$variables) {
  if ($variables['theme_hook_original'] === 'links__language_block') {
    $variables['links']['nl']['link']['#title'] = 'nl';
    $variables['links']['fr']['link']['#title'] = 'fr';
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want that "EN" preffix appear in your URL, go to Administration > Configuration  Regional and language > Languages > Detection and selection , and click "configure" in URL. There, you have to add "EN" preffix to english path.

If you want that "EN" preffix appear in your language switcher block, you can use [Language Switcher Dropdown module](https://www.drupal.org/project/lang_dropdown) with has an option to change long names as "English" for its internacional code ("EN"). I've only used D7 version.